# Customer Email Hacked, Subject line "smtp-mail.outlook.com,587,<email>,<password>"

Tags: email, spam

We've had someone break into our email mailbox - They have sent out spam to in an automated fashion. The only clues is that there is a sent email a few days before with a subject line of

"smtp-mail.outlook.com,587,," to Lm.semen@mail.ru

Would anyone know the attack/virus that would have caused this?

Comment: There are hundreds of ways that someone could have gained access to your email account. The details you have provided will not help to narrow down the options. You need to have an investigation by someone who knows what they are doing to determine how they might have got in and the damage done.

Answer (score 1):

Any simple (even detected as legitimate) script can read the passwords stored by clients like Outlook and then login to your server and spam a lot until eventually external filters down-rep your server.

If the compromised account has administrative privileges on the server it's even more serious.